# INSERT and UPDATE(+ increase values) between two different tables php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
tbl_A
[id | facility_section | assigned_no]
----------
tbl_B
[col1 | col2| issued_to | col3 | col_etc]
----------
```

The drop down list will retrieve values of `facility_section` column of `tbl_A` table. Then, the drop down list values will be inserted into `issued_to` column of `tbl_B`. Code sample:-

```html
<?php

include ('dbconnect.php');

@$i=$_POST['issued_to'];

if(@$_POST['submit'])
{
  $s="INSERT INTO tbl_B (issued_to) VALUES ('$i')";
  mysql_query($s);
}

@$facility_section = $_POST['facility_section'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT facility_section FROM tbl_A");

?>

<select name="issued_to">
  <option selected disabled>-- Please Select --</option>
  <?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "<option value='" . $row['facility_section'] . "'>" . $row['facility_section'] . "</option>";
 }
  ?>
</select>
```

What I want is that, each time the drop down list values is inserted into `issued_to` column of `tbl_B`, `assigned_no` column of `tbl_A` will be updated and increased by 1 where it will be increased accordingly:- `facility_section`=`issued_to`.

I know the code to update:-

`UPDATE tbl_A
 SET assigned_no = assigned_no + 1
 WHERE facility_section = '$facility_section'`

But, I'm stuck on how to do this...

Comment: Is this your full working code?

Comment: If that is your whole code you got a few problems there. 1.) You are accessing $_POST without using a form that has the method=POST tag which means $_POST will be empty forever.  2.) You really should use prepared sql statements

Comment: @LoganWayne and Thomas, No, this is not my full working code.

Comment: You shouldn't use mysql_* functions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Declaring of `$i` should be inside your `if()` condition, or else it will give an `undefined variable` error message.
- What is the purpose of `@$facility_section = $_POST['facility_section'];`? Where did you use it? I think it should also be inside your `if()` condition.
- You are prone to [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php), so you should be using [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) when binding a variable, especially when it is a string, into your query.
- `mysql_*` API is already deprecated, and you should be using `mysqli_*` API instead. Read here about [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Your code should at least look like this (inside `if()` condition):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

  $i = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["issued_to"]);

  $s="INSERT INTO tbl_B (issued_to) VALUES ('$i')";
  mysql_query($s);

  /* GET TOTAL OF tbl_B BASED FROM THE SELECTED facility_section */
  $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_B WHERE issued_to = '$i'");
  $totalrows = mysql_num_rows($res);

  /* UPDATE THE assigned_no COLUMN WITH THE UPDATED NUMBER OF ROWS */
  mysql_query("UPDATE tbl_A assigned_no = '$totalrows' WHERE facility_section='$i'");

} /* END OF ISSET */
```